# How to display last 3-5 records from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I display the last 3 or 5 records in my case posts (my columns in database are `post_id, post_title, post_date, post_text`) in HTML page but in table?

I suppose I know to display records in table but how to edit style of the table, where? I am talking about displaying just last 3 or 5 records not all records from database.

Comment: Order and limit your SQL statement, `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5` should work. You can order it if required.

Comment: @Alwin yep, putting an order makes it clearer that the query has an order to it, for other devs. *imo*

Comment: If you want the _last_ records from the database, you'll need `DESC` not `ASC`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose something like this. Naturally, replace table with your table. Also this question has been asked a million times before here.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 5
    )
    ORDER BY post_id ASC;
```

Comment: Tnx I will try it and hope it will work